# Creating ViewController+CollectionView programmatically and adding it to ScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, instance

I've got a short question. I want to create a ViewController, which has an UICollectionView, programmatically and add this to a ScrollView. If I'm doing this with the Interfacebuilder, everything is working fine. But creating an instance and add it programmatically doesn't work, the CollectionView doesn't appear. Here is the part of my code:

ViewController.m

```
ViewControllerCell* Cell = [[ViewControllerCell alloc]init];
[_contentScrollView addSubview:Cell.view];
```

ViewControllerCell.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
}
```

The light gray background does appear, so I think, that the subview is added, but somehow my collectionview doesn't appear. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Is the contentsize of your scroll view big enough?

Comment: Hmm, good question, with the interfacebuilder I just created a Container View and set its CustomClass to ViewControllerCell.
But I just use the ScrollView for horizontal scrolling, the CollectionView should do vertical scrolling, which works, if I m using interface builder

Comment: First thing, ScollView inside a scrollview is bad. regarding your question , post some more code from `ViewController.m` where you create your scrollview `contentScrollView `

Comment: Why is this bad?     
    _contentScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320*[categories count], 436);

Comment: Sorry,My bad. did not read it right. horizontal scrolling and vertical scrolling, it's fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Check you are adding delegate methods right

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
{
    UICollectionView *_collectionView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    _collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [_collectionView setDelegate:self];

    [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    [_collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:_collectionView];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(40, 40);
}
```

Comment: I just tried this, but it doesn't work. I'm using this: https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout
perhaps this is the problem?

Comment: I don't know why, but if i put this ViewControllerCell* Cell; in @implementation{...} it does work. Can somebody please explain this to me?

Comment: can you show more code?? your code is not clear. ViewController is your CollectionView? and set your ViewController frame before you add to _contentScrollView